# If $x,y \in \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ then is $g(x,y)=xy$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Suppose we assume the convention that $0 \cdot \infty =0$. If $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is the extended real line and $x,y \in \bar{\mathbb{R}}$, then is $g(x,y)=xy$ continuous? Why?

I do not think it is as it seems to depend on the speed of which we take limits $x \to 0$ and $y \to \infty$.

Comment: What topology are you putting on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$?

Comment: $g(x,0)=0\to 0$, $g(x,x)=x^2\to\infty$ $\Rightarrow$ no limit.

Comment: @anomaly Presumably, the open sets containing $\infty$ are of the form $(a,\infty]$, and similarly for $-\infty$. Thus, $\overline{\mathbb R}$ is homeomorphic to $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Sure, but I was trying to get the poster to write down the topology and test the continuity condition directly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the limit:
$$\lim_{t\to0}g(t,\infty)$$
On the right, it's $\infty$; on the left, it's $-\infty$; at the point, it's $0$.